# What is the "meta" key in WP_Term Object?

Tags: term-meta

I thought it would be term meta but that doesn't seem to be correct.

For illustration I've created a category named "Test" with a slug of "test".

I'm updating its term_meta with:

```
update_term_meta( 64, 'test_meta', 'asdfasdf' );
```

This appears in the termmeta table along with other meta keys/values:

[image: data in termmeta table]

get_term(64) returns this:

```
WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 64
    [name] => Test
    [slug] => test
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 64
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 0
    [filter] => raw
    [meta] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Why is `[meta]` empty?

`get_term_meta(64)` returns as expected:

```
Array
(
[headline] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[intro_text] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[display_title] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[display_description] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[doctitle] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[description] => Array
    (
        [0] => Meta desc
    )

[keywords] => Array
    (
        [0] => someMetaKeyword
    )

[layout] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[noindex] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[nofollow] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[noarchive] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

[test_meta] => Array
    (
        [0] => asdfasdf
    )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/#source), that `meta` property isn't a standard property in the `WP_Term` object.

However, a plugin/theme can add *custom* properties to the object using the [`get_term`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_term/) or [`get_{taxonomy}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_taxonomy/) filter:

```php
add_filter( 'get_term', function( $term ){
    $term->meta = get_term_meta( $term->term_id ); // all metadata
    return $term;
} );
```

Comment: Using 2015 theme with only ACF and the plugin I'm working on active.  Tried on a fresh site with the same theme and plugins and I'm not seeing the 'meta' property.  Something must be happening on the first site I'm not aware of.  Thanks!